# Apache Tika: Which jar file contains org.apache.tika.sax.boilerpipe.BoilerpipeContentHandler?

Tags: jar, apache-tika

I am attempting to use Apache Tika 2.7.0.  I cannot find a jar (on Maven Central etc.) which contains org.apache.tika.sax.boilerpipe.  It's not in tika-core where the other org.apache.tika.sax modules reside.  Or do I have to build it myself?

Answer (score 3):

As you probably saw, that handler exists in `tika-parser-html-commons`. You'll have to add that module as a dependency to your code or build the jar yourself.  We include it in `tika-app` and `tika-server-standard`.

If you'd like to have it as a release artifact, please open an issue on our [JIRA](https://issues.apache.org/jira/projects/TIKA).

See [TIKA-1484](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/TIKA-1484) for the background on why we isolated this dependency.

Comment: Got it, thx.  Read the background on the dependency, many thanks.